# Why does my Neo4j 3.0.1 Java API Code throw this error?

Tags: java, eclipse, api, maven, neo4j

I just started working with the Neo4j Java API. I had never used Maven before (because I found it simpler to just add jars to the project) and unfortunately I do not understand the error my code throws.

I code in Eclipse on OS X 10.11, in Eclipse I use M2Eclipse (for Maven projects like this one) and I set my Neo4j DB up using Neo4j Community Edition V 3.0.3 .

I really don't understand this Error. It seems like there is a class missing somewhere but I have no clue why.

This is my code (as I said, I just wanted to try out the API)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
GraphDatabaseFactory f = new GraphDatabaseFactory();

    GraphDatabaseService db = f.newEmbeddedDatabase(new File("/Users/Me/Documents/Neo4j/default.graphdb"));


    try ( Transaction t = db.beginTx() )
    {

        Node johannesNode = db.createNode(KnowledgeComposer.NodeType.PERSON);
        johannesNode.setProperty("Name", "Johannes");
        johannesNode.setProperty("Age", 17);
        johannesNode.setProperty("Class", "Q1");

        Node stuteNode = db.createNode(KnowledgeComposer.NodeType.PERSON);
        stuteNode.setProperty("Name", "Barbara");

        Node annaNode = db.createNode(KnowledgeComposer.NodeType.PERSON);
        annaNode.setProperty("Name", "Anna");
        annaNode.setProperty("Age", 17);
        annaNode.setProperty("Class", "Q1");

        Node davidNode = db.createNode(KnowledgeComposer.NodeType.PERSON);
        davidNode.setProperty("Name", "David");
        davidNode.setProperty("Age", 16);
        davidNode.setProperty("Class", "EF");


        Node stuteLK = db.createNode(KnowledgeComposer.NodeType.COURSE);
        stuteLK.setProperty("Name", "English LK");
        stuteLK.setProperty("Room", "1.11");
        stuteLK.setProperty("Started", 2015);
        stuteLK.setProperty("Ends", 2017);

        Relationship johannesLKRel = johannesNode.createRelationshipTo(stuteLK, RelType.BELONGS_TO);
        johannesLKRel.setProperty("Function", "Student");

        Relationship davidLKRel = davidNode.createRelationshipTo(stuteLK, RelType.BELONGS_TO);
        davidLKRel.setProperty("Function", "Student");

        Relationship stuteLKRel = stuteNode.createRelationshipTo(stuteLK, RelType.BELONGS_TO);
        stuteLKRel.setProperty("Function", "Teacher");

        annaNode.createRelationshipTo(johannesNode, RelType.KNOWS);
        johannesNode.createRelationshipTo(stuteNode, RelType.KNOWS);
        johannesNode.createRelationshipTo(davidNode, RelType.KNOWS);
        davidNode.createRelationshipTo(johannesNode, RelType.KNOWS);
        t.success();
    }

    db.shutdown();
}
```

This is the error it throws

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.CommunityFacadeFactory, /Users/Me/Documents/Neo4j/default.graphdb
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:144)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.CommunityFacadeFactory.newFacade(CommunityFacadeFactory.java:40)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:108)
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:100)
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.lambda$createDatabaseCreator$194(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:89)
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$$Lambda$1/636718812.newDatabase(Unknown Source)
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:183)
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:65)
at de.codej.knowledgecomposer.main.KnowledgeComposer.main(KnowledgeComposer.java:27)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.extension.KernelExtensions@719b03d4' failed to initialize. Please see attached cause exception.
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:416)
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.init(LifeSupport.java:62)
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:98)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:140)
... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/store/Directory
at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.storage.DirectoryFactory.<clinit>(DirectoryFactory.java:55)
at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.LuceneKernelExtensions.lambda$directoryFactory$1(LuceneKernelExtensions.java:30)
at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.LuceneKernelExtensions$$Lambda$54/888350457.apply(Unknown Source)
at org.neo4j.io.fs.DefaultFileSystemAbstraction.getOrCreateThirdPartyFileSystem(DefaultFileSystemAbstraction.java:187)
at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.LuceneKernelExtensions.directoryFactory(LuceneKernelExtensions.java:29)
at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.labelscan.LuceneLabelScanStoreExtension.newInstance(LuceneLabelScanStoreExtension.java:77)
at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.labelscan.LuceneLabelScanStoreExtension.newInstance(LuceneLabelScanStoreExtension.java:40)
at org.neo4j.kernel.extension.KernelExtensions.init(KernelExtensions.java:69)
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:406)
... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.lucene.store.Directory
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 20 more
```

Thank you in advance!

EDIT:

My pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>de.codej</groupId>
<artifactId>KnowledgeComposer</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>KnowledgeComposer</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: would be a good idea to add your pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed a class missing exception. When you get similar errors you can google them to find the required dependencies. Usually a search result from https://mvnrepository.com/ will have the necessary information. In your case, you're missing the org.lucene dependency which can be satisfied if you add the following lines in pom.xml (found [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.neo4j/neo4j-cypher/3.0.1)):

```
<dependencies>
....
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-cypher</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
....
</dependencies>
```